# In Mongoose, what is passed to the callback as the record by Model.find() if no matching records are found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my callback, I am attempting to test whether my call to Model.find() found any results. The `record` passed to the callback for `Model.findOne()`, is `null` but this does not seem to be the case for `Model.find()` which typically "finds" all matching records. So, what exactly is `Model.find()` passing?

Below are various tests I made to try to determine what is being passed to the callback as record:

```
author.model.find({userName: 'nameNotInDB'}, function(err, record)
{
    if(err){console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(record); //~> []
        console.log(record == []); //~> false
        console.log(record == null); //~> false
        console.log(record == undefined); //~> false
        console.log(record == ''); //~> true
        console.log(record === ''); //~> false
        console.log(record == false); //~> true
        console.log(record === false); //~> false
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(typeof record === typeof []) // True
```

Your test (`record == []`) fails because comparing complex types (objects and arrays) will only be true if they are referencing the same object.

Update, better test:

```
console.log(Array.isArray(record)) // True
```